# Conditional XPath expression

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to write a single XPath line that conditionally uses 1 of 2 attribute values depending if one attribute has no value.

Ex.

The logic I'm looking for is...

if @src="" then use @other.

Edited to include that I'm stuck with XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me.

In a nutshell...

concat(../@src,../@other[not(/root/@part_no)])